# SQLite.net Multithread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sqlite

I'm trying to use SQLite in my WPF Application in multithread mode. I'm beginner in C# and I've read lot of post about SQLite and multithreading but... can't achieve to do what I want...

I have made a backgroundWorker which parse different file and then I want to insert into one Database the result of each file into the database.

I'm using the [SQLite.net PCL](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL).

I will not post all the code except if someone ask me, but to make some test I do something like that :

```
lock (_lock)
{
   using (var test = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWin32(), "test.s3db"))
   {
       test.Insert(new MyClassWhichHaveAllField(){Title="XXX"});
   }
}
```

_lock is defined as :

```
public static object _lock = new object();
```

in my backgroundWorker implementation, so as static members.

Even if I put the lock, I received exception "SQLite.Net.SQLiteException: Could not open database file: recipes.s3db (Misuse)"

I try to add some SQLiteOpenFlags like :

```
SQLiteOpenFlags.FullMutex
```

It doesn't change anything.

Thanks you very much...

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using the SQLiteAsync.cs wrapper for multi-threaded ?

[SQliteAsyncConnection and Asynchronous API](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL) further down the page.

Comment: I will try to use it, but how could I be sure when my backgroundworker will finish that all elements is allready insert into the SQLDatabase ?

Comment: And could you explain me why what I have implemented doesn't work ?

Comment: While you create a connection every time you lock it (Which is really slow/bad), you can't control when that connection is closed (destroyed). So the 2nd time through the database will still be open as the GC hasn't closed it yet has it....

Comment: look at the async extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I answer to my question, because indeed, what I have implemented work well except that in my code I wrote :

```
static object _lock = new object();
```

so it was defined as private ...

Thanks you.